# Loop Through Each Sub Directories In Sub Directories

Tags: c#, asp.net, directory, subdirectory

I have a main folder which contains many sub directories. Inside each sub directory, there are many sub directories.

Does anyone knows how can I loop through the many sub directories in each sub directory?

This is my codes currently:

```
if (Directory.Exists(MainDirectory))
{
    foreach (DirectoryInfo SubDir in new DirectoryInfo(MainDirectory).GetDirectories())
    {
        foreach (FileInfo Image in SubDir.GetFiles())
        {
            Image.Delete();
        }
        SubDir.Delete(true);            
    }
    Directory.Delete(MainDirectory, true);
}
```

My current codes will only loop through the images from each subdirectory from the main directory.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `Directory` `SearchOption.AllDirectories` or you can use recursive call for it, whichever is appropriate.

If what you really interested in are files rather than to enter the sub-directories themselves, the method that you can use is `Directory.GetFiles`, something like this:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderpath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories); //"*" denotes all file format
```

the return is `string[]` which contains all filepaths in the given `folderpath` including those which are in the sub-directories.

You can change the `SearchPattern` (`"*"` in the example) to suit the file search pattern (formats) which you need.

If you really need to enter the sub-directory however, you can create recursive calls and in the call, you can check if the directory has further (deeper) folder by using `DirectoryInfo.GetDirectories()`

Comment: Nicely explained +10.

Comment: Welcome, Hope the path is not troubling you anymore.